# How can I mock useMediaQuery in React units tests?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, media-queries

I'm using jest and @testing-library for my units tests in react (typescript).

I have a custom datatable component that uses useMediaQuery to display or not some elements on mobile.

```
const isDesktop = useMediaQuery({
  query: '(min-width: 768px)',
});
```

With this boolean, in my case, I choosed to hide the row selection on mobile with a simple ternary.

In my test, I want to check if the selection checkbox is in the document, but of course it's not.
By removing the mobile condition, the test passes with success, because we render the selection checkbox no matter the screen size.

I conclude that my test environment is like a small screen, so the mobile condition returns true everytime and I cannot test my checkboxes.

(When I say mobile condition, it's of course based on the isDesktop).

Is there a way to mock jest and say before each test "i want that the test screen size is 1500pw width" or something like that ?

I tried something that I saw on an other topic but it does not work for me :

```
    window.matchMedia = jest.fn().mockImplementation((query) => ({
      matches: query === `(min-width: ${utils.breakpoints.md}px)`,
      media: '',
      onchange: null,
      addListener: jest.fn(),
      removeListener: jest.fn(),
    }));
```